# VPN vs VMs and Windows Sandbox

Tags: windows-10, vpn, vmware, hyper-v, windows-sandbox

I am currently running NordVPN on Windows 10. If I have a Guest VM (Windows or Linux) running in Hyper-V or VMware Player on that system, is that VM behind the VPN? What about an instance of Windows Sandbox, is it behind the VPN?

Comment: Depending on the VPN, I have done this:  Access a host from a remote location and then access the guest if I need to. Works.  Sandbox is a limited form of VM so you should be able to access Sandbox, but it is possible that Sandbox security stops this. Certainly accessing regular VMs does work.

Answer (score 1):

VMs can use the host's vpn in general, but it depends on the configuration. Especially if the VPN creates its own network adapter

If the sandbox or VM vswitch is bridged or NAT-ed to the internet-facing adapter, then it may not use the vpn. In those cases, you would need to bridge to the vpn adapter instead. See examples here: [VM share host's VPN connection](https://superuser.com/questions/842489/vm-share-hosts-vpn-connection) or search for "how to connect my VM to the VPN"

Just be aware that disconnecting/removing the VPN adapter while a VM is bridged can really hose its networking

---

Another option is to just run the vpn client on the VM instead of the host