# Sharing a VPN connection from guest to host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I noticed how there are several similar questions but none made me reach the objective.

My goal is to connect my Ubuntu machine to a remote checkpoint VPN.
It looks like no VPN client exists to connect directly.

What I did:

1. I built a Windows VM locally with Oracle VirtualBox.
2. I connect the guest to the VPN.

As a Step 3, I would like to connect the host to the guest VPN but I wasn't able to achieve this.

I set up a NAT network and Host-only network:

- Host: Ubuntu 16.04
- Guest: Win 10 Home
- Guest Host-only network: ipv4 192.168.56.101 gw 192.168.56.1 sub 255.255.255.0
- Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.8
- Target example VPN subnet: 123.123.0.0/24

I tried editing my default (host) gateway as [How to share a VPN connection in a VMWare Guest VM with the Host](https://superuser.com/questions/328592/HOW-TO-SHARE-A-VPN-CONNECTION-IN-A-VMWARE-GUEST-VM-WITH-THE-HOST):

```
sudo add route default 192.168.56.101
```

... looks fine but doesn't work.

I tried saving a route in `/etc/networking/routes 
123.123.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.56.101 any`

... still not working.

I tried with iptables:

```
FORWARD
ACCEPT     all  --  123.123.0.0/24        anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere              anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

I tried this https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/share-vpn-connection-windows/ from the guest but can't start the hostednetwork for some reason.

I'm really out of ideas now. I can setup a different Windows physical computer on the same WiFi, if that can help.

**EDIT:**

At first I actually tried snx solution, this is what the console displays

```
# snx -s 123.123.123.123 -u username -g
Check Point's Linux SNX
build 800005013
Please enter your password:

SNX: Authentication failed
```

while these are the logs in snx.elg

```
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] exists_in_buf: returning 1
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] snx_browser::Receive: state==FIRST_REQ
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] search_for: searching for SESSION_ID= and  ;
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] search_for: prefix not found!
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] parse_page_for_sessionid: session_id not found!
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] snx: quit.
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] snx_browser::~snx_browser: called
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] talkssl::~talkssl: delete link
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] talkssl::end_handler: ending connection
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] snx_browser::Failure: entering with code: 2
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] got link down!- exit
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] talkssl::~talkssl: end
[ 17505 -140036352]@riccardo-notebook[11 May  8:34:03] done
```

Comment: Same issue here, I believe there's no support for a VPN client running on Checkpoint+OTP(RSA SecruID KeyFob) on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error you are having with snx, I think you are using the wrong build. AFAIK (by direct experience), the build 800007075 should work.

See [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/1339119/check-point-vpn-client-alternatives-for-linux).

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work if the VPN server is not configured to allow split tunneling.
In that case, its VPN connection cannot be shared with other computers.

I find it very strange that you cannot find a Checkpoint VPN client for Ubuntu.

Have a look at this
[Checkpoint community article](https://community.checkpoint.com/thread/5564-vpn-client-for-ubuntu)
which provides links and instructions for accessing Checkpoint VPN.

One of the links it provides is to the article
[CheckPoint SNX install instructions for major Linux distributions](http://kenfallon.com/checkpoint-snx-install-instructions-for-major-linux-distributions/) which says :

> As of build 800007075 Checkpoint no longer support using the Native Client on the command line. This prevents scripting logins, and also requires a heavy desktop when we were able to survive with a headless server. Access is still possible, but only via the “SSL Network Extender“. This is a major pain as it requires (from my experience) X server, Oracle Java, and the FireFox browser to run.

The instructions the article gives for Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet are reproduced
below. Adapt them to your Ubuntu version.

> We’re going to install a ppa to get
>   [java](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2015/03/21/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu/),
>   change the root password and install some [additional
>   libraries](http://kenfallon.com/checkpont-snx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/)
>   that are needed to run checkpoint.
>
> ```
> sudo su -
> passwd
> add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
> apt-get update
> apt-get install oracle-java9-installer libstdc++5:i386 libpam0g:i386 libx11-6:i386
> java -version
> ```
>
> Pressing connect will open an xterm window that downloads and runs the
>   native client *install.sh* script. You will need to enter the root
>   password you set earlier, sudo will not work.
>
> Now finally try the Connect > Continue > Accept Key and you should get
>   connected.

Read my entire first link for more information and other methods
at getting Checkpoint VPN working.

Comment: This was actually my first route but I forgot to mention it. If I understood correctly the vpn server doesn't accept connection from linux and browsers, I'll add the logs to my question but in short I get authentication failure (same credentials works with Windows)

Comment: Read the comments in the linked Checkpoint community article for other people who had troubles. Have a look also at [this procedure](https://gist.github.com/rafaeltuelho/899dcf1359cf4d1fbd8a839ea753e535).

Answer (score 0):

I have written an article describing how to share connection from guest to host:
https://krasovs.ky/2021/04/26/checkpoint-snx-adventure.html

The hardest part is NAT. You have to set up snat, simple masquerading doesn't help:

```bsh
GATEWAY=$(ip -o -4 addr show tunsnx | awk '{printf $4}')
nft add rule inet nat postrouting oifname "tunsnx" ip daddr 10.0.0.0/8 snat ip to $GATEWAY
```

Also to make it more flexible I used WireGuard on host and guest to share connection.